# Facebook - prevent people tagging me in comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I have one family member who has a bad habit of tagging me in comments on "SOOOO FUNNNY" images who I have asked to stop but hasn't (and I can't just defriend). I sometimes end up getting friend requests from randoms when she tags me, which gets very annoying. I looked through the entire settings menu and can't find a way to require tag approval in comments like in photos, and I don't seem to be able to untag or delete the comment itself.

Is there a way or will I be forever asking her to stop?

Comment: That's...incredibly annoying. I can see ways to handle being tagged in a post, but being mentioned in a comment just doesn't have the same sort of control. You might change "Who can send me friend requests" to "Friends of Friends", which will stop random people from contacting you, but short of blocking your family member you might be stuck.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent people tagging you in comments. What you can do is *Report* it and/or '*Turn of Notification*'.

Comment: It's 2021 now. Is this still applied?